# How to get date ranges in oracle without using default tables like dual and all_objects

Tags: oracle, performance

I want get the date ranges in Oracle like from 07-jun-2016 to 15-jun-2016.

Output should like

```
07-jun-2016
08-jun-2016
09-jun-2016
10-jun-2016
11-jun-2016
12-jun-2016
13-jun-2016
14-jun-2016
15-jun-2016
```

without using any default tables (because its take more cost while joining some other tables)

Comment: What is wrong with using dual?

Comment: I doubt that it takes more (i.e. significant) cost. Please show us your query.

Comment: You make an unsupported assertion. DUAL is highly optimized. If you think it's a performance bottleneck you need to provide evidence.

Comment: SELECT  TO_DATE('01-05-2018 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-LEVEL+1
FROM dual
WHERE TO_DATE('12-25-2017 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE('01-05-2018 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-LEVEL+1
CONNECT BY LEVEL=ROWNUM; this is the query i got from internet but this query i am joining with 5 or 6 tables its running cost is 4000+ so only i am asking is any other way is there

Comment: When I run your query I'm seeing a cost of 2. Perhaps if you join another 5 or 6 tables to it you're getting a cost of 4000, but the example query you showed does not contribute significantly to your overall query cost. Best of luck.

Comment: i also know mr. Bob Jarvis i am joining this query to more tables so only its cost is increasing

Comment: SELECT TABLE1.ID      AS ID ,TABLE2.NAME                                          AS NAME,TABLE2.TYPE      AS TYPE, TO_DATE('01-10-2017 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-LEVEL+1 AS DATE_OBJ,
  0              AS COUNT1,
  0             AS COUNT2,
  0                       AS COUNT3,
  0          AS COUNT4,
  0          AS COUNT5
  
FROM TABLE TABLE2, TABLE TABLE1,
  DUAL OBJ WHERE TABLE2.ID           = TABLE1.ID
AND TABLE1.TABLE1_TYPE             = 'BASE_TYPE'

Comment: AND TABLE1.ID           = 345664
AND TO_DATE('01-09-2017 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE('01-10-2017 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-LEVEL+1  CONNECT BY LEVEL                    =ROWNUM
GROUP BY ID,  NAME,  TYPE ,  TRUNC(TABLE1.DATE)    TO_DATE('01-10-2017 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-LEVEL+1 ORDER BY DATE_OBJ;

Comment: this is entire query this takes 4000+ costs i dont know why...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get any rows without a table; just use `DUAL`:

Using a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT DATE '2016-06-07' + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2016-06-07' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2016-06-15';
```

or, using a recursive subquery-factoring clause:

```
WITH dates ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2016-06-07' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + 1 FROM dates WHERE dt < DATE '2017-06-15'
)
SELECT * from dates;
```

or, using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DATE '2016-06-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-15' FROM DUAL;
```